# break + return vs return Javascript Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, optimization

I am writing a nodejs Heap and performance is really important. I have the following code:

```
while(true)
if(x)
 do something
 return
if(y)
 do ...
 return
if(z)
 do ...
else
 return
```

I was advised to use

> break

instead of

> return

and put a single return at the end to avoid duplicate code and make it more readable. Is there a performance drop and if so is it anything significant?

In other words:

> Is there a downside for using breaks in a loop only
>   to use return after the loop instead of using return in the first
>   place?

Comment: Not really a performance thing, but if you use `break` instead of `return` you can stick a `return` after your `while` loop and drop the `else` completely, making the code block one line shorter.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - This is a bad "answer" (I know, comment) to a worse question. As currently outlined, the while continues as long as (!x & !y & z), removing the `else` makes it continue as long as (!x & !y). But again, that not a good question anyway. Hard to read, misleading, not clear, and probably meaningless.

Comment: the code is just an example what I was asking is:
Is there a downside for using breaks in a loop only to use return after the loop instead of using return in the first place?

Comment: this is bad question. what if you have some code to run after the loop is done? besides, you have no loop there. if -> return else -> return ... what is the point for while loop there?

Comment: I would guess that there's probably very little in it in terms of performance.  As ever, you'd need to measure it yourself in your environment to find out for sure.  The other side is readability, but that's more opinion based.  Personally, I'd prefer multiple returns.

Comment: I know what the difference between break and return is. I was asking purely in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the following code as an attempt to test this problem:

```
// license: public domain
var mode = process.argv[2] === 'break' ? false : true;
var iterations = process.argv[3] ? process.argv[1] : 1e9;
var testIterations = process.argv[4] ? process.argv[2] : 1e4;
var number;
var range = 1e9;

function testA () {
    for (var i = 0; i < testIterations; i++) {
        number = Math.floor(Math.random() * range);
        if (Math.floor(number/2) === number/2) {
            number = number/2;
            return number;
        }
        if (number * number > number + number) {
            number = number * 2;
            return number;
        }
        if (number) {
            number = Math.pow(2, Math.ceil(Math.random()*16));
            return number;
        }
        if (1 === true || 1 == true) {
            number = number - number*number + Math.pow(number, Math.PI);
            return number;
        }
    }
}

function testB () {
    for (var i = 0; i < testIterations; i++) {
        number = Math.floor(Math.random() * range);
        if (Math.floor(number/2) === number/2) {
            number = number/2;
            break;
        }
        if (number * number > number + number) {
            number = number * 2;
            break;
        }
        if (number) {
            number = Math.pow(2, Math.ceil(Math.random()*16));
            break;
        }
        if (1 === true || 1 == true) {
            number = number - number*number + Math.pow(number, Math.PI);
            break;
        }
    }
    return number;
}

console.log('benchmarking ' + (mode ? 'return' : 'break'));
console.time('benchmark');
if (mode) {
    for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        var result = testA();
    }
} else {
    for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        var result = testB();
    }
}
console.timeEnd('benchmark');
```

Upon execution I got these results (5 samples):

1. benchmarking break: `22262ms`
   benchmarking return: `21947ms`
2. benchmarking break: `22549ms`
   benchmarking return: `22180ms`
3. benchmarking break: `22443ms`
   benchmarking return: `22143ms`
4. benchmarking break: `22304ms`
   benchmarking return: `22109ms`
5. benchmarking break: `22293ms`
   benchmarking return: `22003ms`

Total: break: `111851ms`, return: `110382ms`, difference: `1469ms` (`1.3%`)

If this benchmark code is similar to yours I'd safely say that there is no significant performance difference between both variations.

Comment: Still if performance is critical and there is no difference between them (only coding style) even a 1.3% is ok. Thank you

Comment: If you're planning to change your code based on that benchmark I'd recommend you to run it a few more times, because the 1.3% can still be due to randomness of tests or other stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up:). It is not much to change anyway a few lines but I wanted to know for the future and it does seem logical to take longer.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference I can think of is when using inside a function

```
function x() {
    var i = 1;
    while (i++) {
        console.log(i);
        if (i == 10) break;
    }
    console.log('outside');
};
x();
```

`break` will just exit the loop, but `return` will exit from the function.

Comment: I know what the difference between break and return is. I was asking purely in terms of performance.